# Echo in github actions

Tags: github-actions, gcloud

I'm trying to add some env vars to my `app.yaml` so that they would be visible to `gcloud`.
Currently, I've added those steps:

```
      - run: echo   MONGO_HOST: "${{ secrets.MONGO_HOST }}" >> app.yaml
      - run: echo   MONGO_USER: "${{ secrets.MONGO_USER }}" >> app.yaml
      - run: echo   MONGO_PWD: "${{ secrets.MONGO_PWD }}" >> app.yaml
```

which leads to `bad indentation of a sequence entry` error. I know that the issue is with the `echo` command, but not sure how do use it correctly.

Or, maybe, there is a better way?

Comment: Can you please show the YAML of the entire job?

Comment: The problem could also be quoting: You cannot use `:` on a line unless you correctly quote strings. Try `- run: echo "FOO: ${{ BAR }}" >> app.yaml`

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I've found the solution: used this https://github.com/marketplace/actions/gae-environment-variable-compiler action like this:

```
      - uses: golang-enthusiast/app-yaml-env-compiler@v1.0
        env:
          MONGO_HOST: ${{ secrets.MONGO_HOST }}
          MONGO_USER: ${{ secrets.MONGO_USER }}
          MONGO_PWD: ${{ secrets.MONGO_PWD }}
```

and in the `app.yaml`

```
env_variables:
  MONGO_HOST: $MONGO_HOST
  MONGO_USER: $MONGO_USER
  MONGO_PWD: $MONGO_PWD
```